# What is ICT (IOTA controlled agent)?

Tags: iota-network, raspberry-pi

Recently read CFB's mention of this https://i.redd.it/g3otpb1ydpk01.png -- can't find any more data on it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much information avaiable at the time of this post. All we know is that it will be an IOTA network participant earning iotas by strengthening the network and providing different services. It will have swarm intelligence (many weak devices working together to form a strong one) and basic means of survival.

Source: [come-from-beyond on twitter](https://twitter.com/c___f___b/status/935608935381422080)